# Como crear método que liste el arrayList que le pase siendo de cualquier tipo

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo dos clases que voy exponer a continuación:

Clase Alumno

```
package Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alumno {
    /**
     * nombre del alumno
     * 
     * @var nombre del alumno
     */
    private String nombre;

    /**
     * apellidos del alumno
     * 
     * @var nombre del apellidos
     */
    private String apellidos;

    /**
     * dni del alumno
     * 
     * @var dni del alumno
     */
    private String dni;

    /**
     * Fecha de nacimiento del alumno
     * 
     * @var fechaNacimiento del alumno
     */
    private Fecha fechaNacimiento;

    /**
     * Matriculas que tiene el alumno
     * 
     * @var matriculas del alumno
     */
    private ArrayList<Matricula> matriculas;

    /**
     * Constructor basico
     * 
     * @param nombre nombre del alumno
     * @param apellidos apellidos del alumno
     * @param dni dni del alumno
     * @param fechaNacimiento fecha de nacimiento del alumno
     */
    public Alumno(String nombre, String apellidos, String dni, Fecha fechaNacimiento) {
        this.setNombre(nombre);
        this.setApellidos(apellidos);
        this.setDni(dni);
        this.setFechaNacimiento(fechaNacimiento);
        this.setMatriculas(new ArrayList<Matricula>());
    }

    /**
     * Constructor con matriculas
     * 
     * @param nombre nombre del alumno
     * @param apellidos apellidos del alumno
     * @param dni dni del alumno
     * @param fechaNacimiento fecha de nacimiento del alumno
     * @param matriculas matriculas del alumno
     */
    public Alumno(String nombre, String apellidos, String dni, Fecha fechaNacimiento, ArrayList<Matricula> matriculas) {
        this.setNombre(nombre);
        this.setApellidos(apellidos);
        this.setDni(dni);
        this.setFechaNacimiento(fechaNacimiento);
        this.setMatriculas(matriculas);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alumno alumno = new Alumno();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor que pide los datos del alumno
     */
    public Alumno() {
        Scanner datosAlumno = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre;
        do {
            System.out.print("Nombre: ");
            nombre = datosAlumno.nextLine();
        } while(!this.setNombre(nombre));
        String apellidos;
        do {
            System.out.print("Apellidos: ");
            apellidos = datosAlumno.nextLine();
        } while(!this.setApellidos(apellidos));
        String dni;
        do {
            System.out.print("Dni: ");
            dni = datosAlumno.nextLine();
        } while (!this.setDni(dni));
        System.out.print("Fecha de Nacimiento (dd/mm/aaaa): ");
        Fecha fecha = new Fecha();
        /*String letra;
        do {
            System.out.print("Quieres añadir una matricula para el Alumno?(s/n): ");
            letra = datosAlumno.nextLine();
        } while (!(letra.equalsIgnoreCase("s") || letra.equalsIgnoreCase("n")));
        if (letra.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {

        }*/
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el nombre del alumno
     * 
     * @return nombre del alumno
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Establece el nombre de el alumno
     * 
     * @param nombre nombre del alumno
     */
    public boolean setNombre(String nombre) {
        if (!nombre.equals("")) {
            this.nombre = this.capitalizar(nombre);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No puedes dejar el nombre vacío, vuelve a introducirlo");
            return false;
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve los apellidos del alumno
     * 
     * @return apellidos del alumno
     */
    public String getApellidos() {
        return this.apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * Establece los apellidos de el alumno
     * 
     * @param apellidos apellidos del alumno
     */
    public boolean setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        if (!apellidos.equals("")) {
            this.apellidos = this.capitalizar(apellidos);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No puedes dejar los apellidos vacíos, vuelve a introducirlo");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el dni del alumno con letra
     * 
     * @return dni del alumno
     */
    public String getDni() {
        String letras="TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
        return this.dni+letras.charAt(Integer.parseInt(this.dni)%23);
    }

    /**
     * Establece el dni del alumno
     * 
     * @param dni del alumno
     */
    public boolean setDni(String dni) {
        if (dni.length() == 8 && this.isNumeric(dni)) {
            this.dni = dni;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("El dni introducido no es correcto");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve la fecha de nacimiento del alumno
     * 
     * @return fecha de nacimiento del alumno
     */
    public Fecha getFechaNacimiento() {
        return this.fechaNacimiento;
    }

    /**
     * Establece la fecha de nacimiento del alumno
     * 
     * @param fechaNacimiento fecha de nacimiento de el alumno
     */
    public void setFechaNacimiento(Fecha fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve las matriculas del usuario
     * 
     * @return matriculas del usuario
     */
    public ArrayList<Matricula> getMatriculas() {
        return this.matriculas;
    }

    /**
     * Establece las matriculas de el alumno
     * 
     * @param matriculas matricuals del alumno
     */
    public void setMatriculas(ArrayList<Matricula> matriculas) {
        this.matriculas = matriculas;
    }

    /**
     * Esta matriucla ya la tiene el alumno
     * 
     * @param matricula matricula que se le va añadir al alumno
     * @return true si se añade, false si ya tiene esa matricula
     */
    public boolean addMatricula(Matricula matricula) {
        if (!this.matriculas.contains(matricula)) {
            this.matriculas.add(matricula);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Esta matricula ya la tiene el alumno");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Edita una matriucla
     * 
     * @param matricula matricula a editar
     * @param matriculaNueva matricula editada
     * @return true si se edita, false si no lo hace
     */
    public boolean editarMatricula(Matricula matricula, Matricula matriculaNueva) {
        if (!this.matriculas.contains(matricula)) {
            System.out.println("La matricula que quieres editar no existe");
            return false;
        } else if (this.matriculas.contains(matriculaNueva)) {
            System.out.println("La matricula por la que la queires sustituir ya existe");
            return false;
        } else {
            this.matriculas.set(this.matriculas.indexOf(matricula), matriculaNueva);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Borrar una matricula
     * 
     * @param matricula matricula a eliminar
     * @return true si se elimina false si no lo hace
     */
    public boolean removeMatricula(Matricula matricula) {
        if (this.matriculas.contains(matricula)) {
            this.matriculas.remove(matricula);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Esta asignatura no existe, por lo que no se puede borrar");
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Capitaliza el String que le pasemos aunque sea compuesto
     * jUan caRLOs -> Juan Carlos
     * 
     * @param stringCapitalizar string que queremos capitalizar
     * @return string capitalizado
     */
    private String capitalizar(String capitalizar) {

        String capitalizado="";
        capitalizar=capitalizar.toLowerCase().trim();
        boolean mayus=true;

        for (int i = 0; i < capitalizar.length(); i++) {
          if (capitalizar.charAt(i)==' ') {
            mayus=true;
          }
          if (mayus==true && capitalizar.charAt(i)!=' ') {
            capitalizado=capitalizado+(capitalizar.charAt(i)+"").toUpperCase();
            mayus=false;
          }else{
            capitalizado=capitalizado+capitalizar.charAt(i);
          }
        }
        return capitalizado;
    }

    /**
     * Comprueba que una cadena de texto sea Numerica
     * 
     * @param cadena cadena para comprobar
     * @return true si es numerica, false si no lo es
     */
    private boolean isNumeric(String cadena){
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Profesor

```
package Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Profesor {
    /**
     * Nombre del profesor
     * 
     * @var nombre del profesor
     */
    private String nombre;

    /**
     * Apellidos del profesor
     * 
     * @var apellidos del profesor
     */
    private String apellidos;

    /**
     * Titulacion del profesor
     * 
     * @var titulacion del profesor
     */
    private String titulacion;

    /**
     * Asignaturas que imparte
     * 
     * @var asignaturas que imparte el profesor
     */
    private ArrayList<Asignatura> asignaturas;

    /**
     * Constructor que pide los datos de profesor
     */
    public Profesor() {
        this.asignaturas = new ArrayList<Asignatura>();
        Scanner datosProfesor = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombre;
        do {
            System.out.print("Nombre: ");
            nombre = datosProfesor.nextLine();
        } while(this.setNombre(nombre));
        String apellidos;
        do {
            System.out.print("Apellidos: ");
            apellidos = datosProfesor.nextLine();
        } while(this.setApellidos(apellidos));
        String titulacion;
        do {
            System.out.print("Titulación: ");
            titulacion = datosProfesor.nextLine();
        } while (this.setTitulacion(titulacion));
        System.out.println("AÑADIR ASIGNATURAS");
        String letra;
        do {
            System.out.print("Añadir Asignatura? (s/n): ");
            letra = datosProfesor.nextLine();
            if (letra.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                Asignatura asig = new Asignatura();
                this.asignaturas.add(asig);
            }
        } while (letra.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
        System.out.println("PROFESOR: "+this.nombre+" DADO DE ALTA CORRETAMENTE");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Profesor p = new Profesor();

        /*Tema t1 = new Tema("Tema 1", 20);
        Tema t2 = new Tema("Tema 2", 2000);
        Tema t3 = new Tema("Tema 3", 2000);
        Tema t4 = new Tema("Tema 4", 20);
        Temario temario = new Temario("Temario 1");
        temario.addTema(t1);
        temario.addTema(t4);

        Asignatura asignatura1 = new Asignatura("Lengua", temario);

        Temario temario2 = new Temario("Temario 2");
        temario2.addTema(t2);
        temario2.addTema(t3);

        Asignatura asignatura2 = new Asignatura("Mates", temario2);

        Temario temario3 = new Temario("Temario 3");
        temario3.addTema(t2);
        temario3.addTema(t3);

        Asignatura asignatura3 = new Asignatura("Física", temario3);

        Profesor profesor = new Profesor("Rubeniguen magnun", "Vera álvarez", "Ingeniero");
        profesor.addAsignatura(asignatura1);
        profesor.updateAsignatura(asignatura1, asignatura3);*/
    }

    /**
     * Constructor basico
     * 
     * @param nombre nombre del profesor
     * @param apellidos apellidos del profesor
     * @param titulacion titulacion del profesor
     */
    public Profesor(String nombre, String apellidos, String titulacion) {
        this.setNombre(nombre);
        this.setApellidos(apellidos);
        this.setTitulacion(titulacion);
        this.setAsignaturas(new ArrayList<Asignatura>());
    }

    /**
     * Constructor con asignaturas
     * 
     * @param nombre nombre del profesor
     * @param apellidos apellidos del profesor
     * @param titulacion titulacion del profesor
     * @param asignaturas asignaturas que imaparte el profesor
     */
    public Profesor(String nombre, String apellidos,String titulacion, ArrayList<Asignatura> asignaturas) {
        this.setNombre(nombre);
        this.setApellidos(apellidos);
        this.setTitulacion(titulacion);
        this.setAsignaturas(asignaturas);
    }

    /**
     * Establece el nombre del profesor
     * 
     * @param nombre nombre del profesor
     */
    public boolean setNombre(String nombre) {
        if (!nombre.equals("")) {
            this.nombre = this.capitalizar(nombre);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el nombre del profesor
     * 
     * @return nonbre del profesor
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Establece los apellidos del profesor
     * 
     * @param apellidos apellidos del profesor
     */
    public boolean setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        if (!apellidos.equals("")) {
            this.apellidos = this.capitalizar(apellidos);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Devuelve los apellidos del profesor
     * 
     * @return apellidos del profesor
     */
    public String getApellidos() {
        return this.apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * Establece la titulacion del profesor
     * 
     * @param titulacion titulacion del profesor
     */
    public boolean setTitulacion(String titulacion) {
        if (!titulacion.equals("")) {
            this.titulacion = titulacion.toUpperCase();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve la titulacion del profesor
     * 
     * @return titulacion del profesor
     */
    public String getTitulacion() {
        return this.titulacion;
    }

    /**
     * Establece las asignaturas que imparte el profesor
     * 
     * @param asignaturas asignaturas que imparte el profesor
     */
    public void setAsignaturas(ArrayList<Asignatura> asignaturas) {
        int horasTotales = 0;
        for (Asignatura asignatura:asignaturas) {
            horasTotales += asignatura.getTemario().getHorasTotales();  
        }

        if (horasTotales >= 0 && horasTotales<=3000) {
            this.asignaturas = asignaturas;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Las asignaturas superaban las horas lectivas por profesor permitidas");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Devuelve las asignaturas que imparte el profesor
     * 
     * @return asignaturas que imparte el profesor
     */
    public ArrayList<Asignatura> getAsignaturas() {
        return asignaturas;
    }

    /**
     * Añade una asignatura al profesor
     * Comprueba que el profesor no tenga la asignatura ya añadida
     * 
     * @param asignatura asignatura a añadir al profesor
     */
    public boolean addAsignatura(Asignatura asignatura) {
        if (this.asignaturas.contains(asignatura)) {
            System.out.println("El profesor ya imparte esta asignatura");
            return true;
        } else {
            int horasTotales = this.getHorasTotalesProfesor() + asignatura.getTemario().getHorasTotales();
            if (horasTotales <= 3000 && horasTotales >= 0) {
                this.asignaturas.add(asignatura);
                return false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("La asignatura no se ha podido añadir porque con ella se sobrepasan las horas lectivas maximas que puede tener el profesor");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Elimina una asignatura al profesor
     * Comprueba que la asignatura exista antes de eliminarla
     * 
     * @param asignatura asignatura a eliminar
     */
    public void removeAsignatura(Asignatura asignatura) {
        if (this.asignaturas.contains(asignatura)) {
            this.asignaturas.remove(asignatura);
        } else {
            System.out.println("El profesor no imparte la asignatura que quieres eliminarle");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hace un update de la asignatura especificada
     * Comprueba que la asignatuira a modificar existe y que por la que se va modificar no este ya en sus asignaturas
     * 
     * @param asignatura asignatura a modificar
     * @param asignaturaNueva asignatura por la que se va modificar
     */
    public void updateAsignatura(Asignatura asignatura, Asignatura asignaturaNueva) {
        if (this.asignaturas.contains(asignatura) && !this.asignaturas.contains(asignaturaNueva)){
            int horasTotales = this.getHorasTotalesProfesor() + asignaturaNueva.getTemario().getHorasTotales();
            if (horasTotales <= 3000 && horasTotales >= 0) {
                this.asignaturas.set(this.asignaturas.indexOf(asignatura), asignaturaNueva);
            } else {
                System.out.println("La asignatura no se ha podido modifcar porque con ella se sobrepasan las horas lectivas maximas que puede tener el profesor");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("La asignatura que quieres modificar no existe o ya la tiene asignada el profesor");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calcula las horas totales que esta dando el profesor
     * 
     * @return horas totales que esta dando el profesor
     */
    private int getHorasTotalesProfesor() {
        int horasTotales = 0;
        for (Asignatura asignatura:this.asignaturas) {
            horasTotales += asignatura.getTemario().getHorasTotales();
        }
        return horasTotales;
    }

    /**
     * Capitaliza el String que le pasemos aunque sea compuesto
     * jUan caRLOs -> Juan Carlos
     * 
     * @param stringCapitalizar string que queremos capitalizar
     * @return string capitalizado
     */
    private String capitalizar(String capitalizar) {

        String capitalizado="";
        capitalizar=capitalizar.toLowerCase().trim();
        boolean mayus=true;

        for (int i = 0; i < capitalizar.length(); i++) {
          if (capitalizar.charAt(i)==' ') {
            mayus=true;
          }
          if (mayus==true && capitalizar.charAt(i)!=' ') {
            capitalizado=capitalizado+(capitalizar.charAt(i)+"").toUpperCase();
            mayus=false;
          }else{
            capitalizado=capitalizado+capitalizar.charAt(i);
          }
        }
        return capitalizado;
    }
}
```

Como podría crear un método que pasándole un arrayList de lo que sea, por ejemplo Le paso un ArrayList de alumnos y debe de listarlos, le paso uno de Profesores y debe listarlo, le paso uno de juguetes y debe listarlo, se como hacerlo pasando un arrayList de Object y listándolo ya que todas la clases provienen de Object, pero sabes que hay otra manera mas correcta de hacerlo pero no conseguimos dar con ella

Comment: Tu respuesta esta utilizando generics... 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: En tu caso no es necesario utilizar genéricos, ya que solo necesitas listar los elementos (si con listar te refieres a mostrar el resultados del `toString()`), ya que todas las clases heredan el método `toString()` de `Object`.

Comment: @E.Betanzos No es necesario pero queda mucho más *limpio*

Comment: En Java, los genéricos no existen para escribir un código limpio, existen para poder definir en tiempo de compilación el tipo de dato con el que vamos a trabajar en, por ejemplpo, una estructura de datos (como las colecciones). Tuviera sentido utilizar genéricos su el método en vez de retornar `void` tuviese que retornar el mismo tipo de dato de los elementos de la lista que se le pasa como parámetro, en caso contrario, lejos de "quedar más limpio" lo que puede hacer es confundir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es algo como:

```
private void <T> listar(List<T> lista) {
    for (T elemento: lista) {
        System.out.println(elemento.toString());
    }
}
```